# How does the 100 multiple senders rule in GCM apply?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Refering to this information about multiple senders for the same application: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#multi-senders

Assuming I have a news aggregation app, like described in the text. Is it possible for each installtion to have 100 individual senders that are completely independent from any other senders that are registered on any other device using the same application.

It pretty much sounds so, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

What is written is that if there are 100 messages in queue to be sent to device (e.g. because device is offline) then these 100 messages will be discarded and special message "you have too many messages" will be put to queue.

Comment: Check the link I added. I know what you mean, but this is something completely different. Its about having multiple senders for the same application.